# Have supervisor run via http_proxy list

Tags: go, supervisord

I current have a golang program that I have a supervisor config file like such

```
[program:yout_go]
command = /bin/sh -c 'http_proxy=user:password@123.123.123.123 /home/www/program -env prod'
directory = /home/www/
enviroment=PATH='/home/www/env/bin:/usr/bin'
user = user
autorestart = true
stderr_logfile = /var/log/program/err.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/program/out.log
```

Currently I am running it via 1 proxy, but I want to have it run through more proxies.

Is there any way I can do this? Such as having the http_proxy pull from a list of proxies or do I have to make the goprogram run through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go http package uses the `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` environment variables like other programs, and looks for a single url.

If you want to rotate through multiple proxies, you need to provide a custom `Proxy` function to your [`http.Transport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport), rather than rely on the default [`http.ProxyFromEnvironment`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment).